# How to handle generically item and items fetch from endpoints in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

There is a generic function handling fetching the data from endpoint:

```
protected getData<T>(path: string): Observable<T> {
      return this.http.get<T>(path);
    });
  }
```

The endpoint returns such data for list of cars:

```
{
   items: [ {carName: 'VMW'}, {carName: 'PVC'} ]
}
```

or such data for a particular car:

```
{
   carName: 'PVC'
}
```

What is the proper solution to handle these two situations?

- Create separate generic method to get items, getItems vs getItem
- Introduce 'items' as a generic parameter to provide to getData generic function where getData handles extracting data
- Don't introduce 'items' but handle two variants in one function?

Any other solution that is nicer?

Comment: So you have one function that returns two different response structures?

Comment: @martin does this question contain an answer? :)

Comment: Could you describe the problem in more detail? I read the question, but cannot understand what you're asking about. You have the generic function that fetches different data structures. It is reasonable to create two different types, like `GetCarResponse` & `GetCarsResponse` and fetch them like `getData<GetCarResponse>("get/car")` & `getData<getCarsResponse>("get/cars")`